# Increment numbers at end of alphanumeric string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have alphanumeric strings that will always end in a number, but which may have other numbers embedded early on.

I need to increment the numeric ending and return new ID numbers.

Example:

```
A48-DBD7-398
```

Which will be incremented in a loop:

```
A48-DBD7-398
A48-DBD7-399
A48-DBD7-400
```

How do I separate out the numeric tail from the rest of the string, and then save the two parts into different variables?

*I found several other S.O. questions that split numbers out of a string, but they cannot handle mixed alphanumeric characters in the first part -- or else they split out ALL the numbers, regardless where they are. I need to get only the trailing digits.*

---

### Update

I found a case where my solution does not work:

```
ABC123-DE45-1
```

Duplicates as:

```
ABC2
ABC3
ABC4
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/709ayh4r/1/)

Comment: I don't understand why splitting numbers would require purely alpha first part? If you know that the id starts at the last hyphen, splitting would work and would be the best solution by far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My 2 cents: use regex to identify the pattern and increment the last part.

```
function incrementAlphanumeric(str) {
  const numPart = str.match(/(0?[1-9])+$|0?([1-9]+?0+)$/)[0];
  const strPart = str.slice(0, str.indexOf(numPart));
  const isLastIndexNine = numPart.match(/9$/);

  // If we have a leading zero (e.g. - 'L100A099') 
  // or there is no prefix - we should just increment the number
  if (isLastIndexNine || strPart != null) {
    return strPart + numPart.replace(/\d+$/, (n) => ++n );     
  }
  // Increment the number and add the missing zero
  else {
    return strPart + '0' + numPart.replace(/\d+$/, (n) => ++n );   
  }
}
```

works with the following formats for example:

- TEST01A06
- TEST-100-A100
- TEST0001B-101
- TEST001A100
- TEST001A91
- TEST1101
- TEST1010
- 1010

Demo Repl - https://repl.it/@EdoMagen/Increment-alphanumeric-string

Comment: TEST01A005 -> TEST01A06 instead of TEST01A006

Comment: If you specify "0" it doesn't return "1", seems like the most simple case is overlooked :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in a different approach you could do something like this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var value = $('#in').val(); // get value
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        value = value.replace(/(\d+)$/, function (match, n) {
            return ++n; // parse to int and increment number
        }); // replace using pattern
        $('#result')[0].innerHTML += '<br>' + value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution is definitely an improvement [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/709ayh4r/2/). Thank you +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution, in case it helps

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var ser = $('#in').val();
  var arr = ser.split("-");

  var num = parseInt(arr[arr.length - 1]);
  arr.splice(-1, 1);
  var str = arr.join ('-');  

  for (n = 1; n <= 5; n++) {
    num++;       
    ser = str + '-' + num;    
    $('#result').html($('#result').html() + '<br>' + ser);
  }
});
```

```css
div{width:80%;margin-top:30px;background:wheat;}
```

```html
<input id="in" type="text" value="ABC123-DE45-1" />
<button>Go</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and am posting the question for future seekers.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/709ayh4r/)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="in" type="text" value="A48-DBD7-395" />
<button>Go</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**js/jQ:**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var ser = $('#in').val();
    var num = parseInt(ser.match(/\d+$/));
    var pos = ser.indexOf(num);
    var str = ser.slice(0,pos);

    for (n=1;n<=5;n++){
        num++;
        ser = str + num;
        $('#result').html( $('#result').html() +'<br>'+ser);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const s = "A48-DBD7-398";
s.split('-').reduce((a,b)=>{
      if(Number(b)){b = Number(b) + 1}
      return a +'-'+ b; 
    })

> "A48-DBD7-399"
```

Comment: Nothing in the OP's question states that there will always be hyphens in between the different parts. Your solution will only work when there are hyphens.